# how do I make my textured objects look textured in my render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, procedural

As you can see on this top image it looks textured. This is in textured mode in the Eevee engine and it looks exactly the same in Cycles.
[image: Enter]

This Image is what it looks like if it was rendered. It looks very different because it has no texture besides the brick texture. How do I make it look like the textured version?
[image]

Comment: your question is not clear, did you do the first one? if so, why are you asking how to do it?

Comment: Did you read my entire post? I state clearly what I want

Comment: you say "it has no texture besides the brick texture", do you mean you should see the dirty texture in render mode but can't see it? Maybe show your Shader Editor or even share your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the render panel/tab you must select to bake "Combined." My error was that I selected "Diffuse"

Comment: so was your question about baking?